# Checkbox carries the value but not the title

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor, ef-code-first

I have a many to many relationship which I have implemented and works perfectly, now I want to have a set of checkboxes on the "insert" page of one of the entities that can insert data in the intermediary table.

I have a ViewModel, which contains an array of the following class:

```
class CategoryManager {
   public int id { get; set; }
   public string Title { get; set; }
   public bool Checked { get; set; }
}
```

On the View, I have the following Line to create the checkboxes for each of the array members:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Model.categories.Count(); i++)
    {
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.categories[i].Checked)<i>&nbsp</i>
        @Model.categories[i].Title <br/>
    }
```

Now the thing I have noticed is when the page is submitted and the whole ViewModel is sent back to the controller, in the array of "CategoryManager"s, each instance has the ID and the "Checked" passe through properly (depending on whether the user marked the checkbox or not), however, the "Title" for all of them is NULL.

I know this should be a very basic thing I'm missing, but I am a newby ;)

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't generate a control for property `Title` (or for `ID` so not sure how you are posting that back back). Add a hidden input for the `Title` property

```
for (int i = 0; i < Model.categories.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.categories[i].Checked)
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.categories[i].Checked, "Model.categories[i].Title")
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.categories[i].ID)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.categories[i].ID)
}
```

Note the use of `LabelFor()` to create a label associated with the checkbox.